# Way to get the value of an empifical cdf

Tags: r, cdf

All,

I have an array as follows:

```
x=runif(1)
cdf=cumsum(c(.2,.5,.1,.05,.05,.01,.09))
>p
[1] 0.20 0.70 0.80 0.85 0.90 0.91 1.00
```

How do I return the index of the corresponding cdf entry for x? for example, .1 would return 1, .98 would return 7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `findInterval`, e.g.:

```
findInterval(c(0.1, 0.98), cdf) + 1
# [1] 1 7
```

Answer (score 3):

As @sgibb demonstrates `findInterval` is the right tool for that job. (I do not think that "empirical cdf" is the right term for what you want since the `ecdf` will return a value in the range of the values. You are requesting the "order statistic".  I added the closest available tag, but since SO is really not a statistics website the more narrow tag of "order statistic" is not found.) I have taken to surrounding my 'vec' arguments with `-Inf` and `Inf` ( rather than incrementing the returned values by 1):

```
> findInterval(c(0.1, 0.98), c(-Inf,cdf,Inf)) 
[1] 1 7
```

Comment: Good answer thanks, just chose the one that came in first since they are similar.